# Inside-out plotly sunburst? (r/shiny)

Tags: r, shiny, plotly, sunburst-diagram

What I'm trying to achieve is to plot a donut inside a donut and then some lines between the slices of the inner donut.

Have been looking at plotly's sunburst diagram, but that is exactly 'inside-out' for my purposes. The sunburst has the root at its center and its branches outward. Makes sense, but since I only need one layer of children under the parent layer, I want the parents on the outside and the children on the inside. That's because I need to connect these children with lines and then it's just logical to have these on the inside.

But: I cannot find any option on the sunburst to 'invert' its direction from outward to inward. Does such an option exist with the sunburst diagram? Or should I change strategy to adding two individual donuts and then sync their appearance (how)?

Current code:

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)

ui <- fluidPage(
  plotlyOutput("plot")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    # Read csv containing three columns named ids, labels, parents
    dtRutte3 <- read.csv("Herverkaveling.Rutte3.csv", sep=';', fileEncoding="Windows-1252")
    
    output$plot <- renderPlotly({
        fig <- plot_ly() 
        fig <- fig %>%
            add_trace(
                ids = dtRutte3$ids,
                labels = dtRutte3$labels,
                parents = dtRutte3$parents,
                type = 'sunburst',
                maxdepth = 2,
                domain = list(column = 0)
            ) 
        fig
    })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Data sample:

```
dtRutte3 <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
  ids = c("I","IIA","IIB","III","I.1",
          "I.2","I.3","IIA.1","IIA.2","IIA.3","IIA.4",
          "IIA.10","IIA.10","IIB.1","IIB.2","IIB.3","IIB.4",
          "IIB.6","IIB.7","IIB.8","IIB.9","IIB.10","IIB.10","III.1",
          "III.4","III.5"),
  labels = c("De Koning","Staten-Generaal",
             "Overige Hoge Colleges van Staat, Kabinetten en de Kiesraad","Algemene Zaken",
             "Grondwettelijke uitkering aan de leden vh Koninklijk Huis",
             "Functionele uitgaven van de Koning","Doorbelaste uitgaven van andere begrotingen",
             "Wetgeving en controle Eerste Kamer",
             "Uitgaven tbv van (oud) leden Tweede Kamer en leden EP",
             "Wetgeving en controle Tweede Kamer",
             "Wetgeving en controle Eerste en Tweede Kamer","Nog onverdeeld","Nominaal en onvoorzien",
             "Raad van State","Algemene Rekenkamer",
             "De Nationale Ombudsman","Kanselarij der Nederlandse Orden",
             "Kabinet van de Gouverneur van Aruba",
             "Kabinet van de Gouverneur van Curaçao","Kabinet van de Gouverneur van Sint Maarten",
             "Kiesraad","Nog onverdeeld","Nominaal en onvoorzien",
             "Bevorderen eenheid regeringsbeleid","Kabinet van de Koning",
             "Cie voor toezicht op de Inlichtingen- en veiligheidsdiensten"),
  parents = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,"I","I","I",
              "IIA","IIA","IIA","IIA","IIA","IIA","IIB","IIB",
              "IIB","IIB","IIB","IIB","IIB","IIB","IIB","IIB",
              "III","III","III")
)
```

Comment: I fear this won't work with plotly's sunburst implementation. Parents can have multiple children but not vice versa. Furthermore, afaik there is no option to invert the plot. By the way: please use the output of `dput(dtRutte3)` or `dput(head(dtRutte3, 20))` to share your data.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about dput. Will do next time!

Comment: I guess it'll be two different but sync'ed donuts then. Thanks!