# Reverse order of roots and leaves in Plotly's sunburst

Tags: python, plotly, sunburst-diagram

I am plotting hierarchical data as a sunburst with `Plotly`'s `plotly.express.sunburst()` in Python. However, I'd like to reverse the order of the categories (with the most broad category inhabiting the outer ring and child categories the inner ones).

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.DataFrame(data = {'Hierarchy 1': ['Dark', 'Dark', 'Dark', 'Bright'], 'Hierarchy 2': ['Grey', 'Black', 'Blue', 'Bright'], 'values': [1, 2, 3, 4]})
fig = px.sunburst(df, path = ['Hierarchy 1', 'Hierarchy 2'], values = 'values')
plotly.offline.plot(fig)
```

Simply reversing the list for path does not do the trick unfort as this does not plot the outer ring all the way through in that case but includes the boarders.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Answer (not possible) here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68436968/inside-out-plotly-sunburst-r-shiny

Comment: The link you posted leads to R.  I was looking for solutions in Python as the guy who asked the Q.